# React Router Dom MoMatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

как сделать `NoMatch` роут если у нас есть вложенный `Switch`?
Так как я сделал не работает, и вместо `NotFound` открывает пустую страницу. Но, если убрать `Switch` с рутой `Loc`, то будет отображаться компонент `NotFound` если мы забъем несуществующий адрес.

К примеру:

```js
<Router>
  <Fragment>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Switch>
        <Route  path="/loc" component={Loc} />
      </Switch>
      <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </Fragment>
</Router>
```

Comment: а зачем вложенный switch?  если не секрет

Comment: @СергейПетрашко у `Loc` будет вложенные ссылки `/loc/:id`